# Find a permutation of numbers 1 through N such that average of any two numbers in the permutation does not occur between them

Tags: algorithm, math, permutation

for eg: For N = 4, [1,3,2,4] is a solution permutation but [1,4,2,3] is not because 2 occurs between 1 and 3.

I was reading through this blog post that works out this problem.
https://kartikkukreja.wordpress.com/2014/11/04/interesting-problem-multiple-solutions/

I am unable to understand the divide and conquer approach to this problem which is based on the fact that the average of an odd and even number would not be an integer and hence need not be cared about. I am having trouble understanding how the logic proceeds after the first divide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how you reduce this problem to smaller problems:

1. Suppose all of your input numbers are even. Then, divide all the numbers by 2 and solve for them, and finally multiply all the numbers by 2.
2. Suppose all of your input numbers are odd. Then, add 1 to all numbers, then solve for them, and finally subtract 1 from all numbers.
3. Suppose some numbers are odd and some are even. Then, solve for the odd numbers first, and then for the even numbers, and contcatenate the two results.

For example, for the given input vector (1,2,3,4,5,6,7):

```
P([1,2,3,4,5,6,7]) := P([1,3,5,7]) + P([2,4,6])

P([1,3,5,7]) := P([2,4,6,8]) - 1 = 
  P([1,2,3,4]) * 2 - 1 = 
  ( P([1,3]) + P([2,4]) ) * 2 - 1 = 
  [1,3,2,4] * 2 - 1 = [2,6,4,8] - 1 = [1,5,3,7]

P([2,4,6]) := P([1,2,3]) * 2 = [1,3,2] * 2 = [2,6,4]
```

so eventually

```
P([1,2,3,4,5,6,7]) = [1,5,3,7,2,6,4]
```